# How to fix "expected ')' before '['

Tags: c, syntax-error

I keep trying to compile this program, but I keep coming up with the error: 
"expected ')' before '[' token" near the bottom where the function1 is being declared.. the code I have there looks good to me so I am not really quite sure what is going on.. Please shed some light onto this, I'm pretty much a noob at C so please be nice..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>


#define maxrow 20  //defines maxrow as a constant of 20
#define maxcol 30  //defines maxcol as a constant of 30


void function1(char array[][maxcol]);
void function4(int, int); //function to display the pairs count


int main( void )
{  



int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
int countX = 0;
int countY = 0;
srandom( (unsigned) time(NULL) );
char array[maxrow][maxcol];


function1(array);

/*
for (x=0;x<maxrow;x++)
    {
     for (y=0;y<maxcol;y++)
        {
         array[x][y] = random() % 26 + 'A';
         printf("%c ", array[x][y]);
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
printf("\n");
*/


for (row=0;row<maxrow-1;row++)
    {
     for (col=0;col<maxcol; col++)
        {
         if (array[row][col] == array[row+1][col])
           {
            countX++;
           }
        }
    }

for(col=0;col<maxcol-1;col++)
    {
     for (row=0;row<maxrow;row++)
        {
         if (array[row][col] == array[row][col+1])
           {
            countY++;
           }
        }
    }



function4 (countX, countY);


    return ( 0 ) ;

}    // MARKS THE END OF THE main( ) BLOCK OF STATEMENTS
```

this is where the error is:

```
void function1(array[][maxcol])
    {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

     for (x=0;x<maxrow;x++)
        {
             for (y=0;y<maxcol;y++)
                {
                 array[x][y] = random() % 26 + 'A';
                 printf("%c ", array[x][y]);
                }
         printf("\n");
        }
    printf("\n");

    return(array[x][y]);
    }


void function4(int countX, int countY)
    {
    printf("\nNumber of horizontal pairs: %d\n", countX);
    printf("\nNumber of vertical pairs: %d\n\n", countY);

    }
```

Comment: At which line does the error appear at? Would it reside on the same line as your function delcaraion? Take a look at your function arguments

Comment: Check if all your `{ }`, `( )`, and `[]`s match properly.

Comment: Please try to give functions descriptive names.  You wouldn't call your children `child1` and `child2` would you?

Comment: @paddy: no, of course not; programmers count from 0, so they'd be `child0` and `child1`.

Comment: After getting answers, editing the question is a bad idea.

Comment: When I see "this is where the error is:", I expect one line to follow, not the majority of the program. And as haccks noted, it's bad, very very bad, to correct the code in your question to eliminate the error ... why would you do such a thing?

Comment: @JimBalter because I didn't know it wasn't a good thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
void function1(array[][maxcol])  
         //    ^type missing
```

to

```
void function1(char array[][maxcol])
```

Also you cannot return anything from a function with return type `void`. The statement

```
 return(array[x][y]);
```

should not be there.

Comment: Good spotting.  Also, they should not return a value from this function.

Comment: @paddy and haccks:: Thanks for your help guys! I fixed my code for anyone who may need this type of thing in the future

Comment: @nom_nutella If this answers your posted question, you should mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @nom_nutella : If this answer solve your problem, please click on tick mark to accept this answer.

Comment: Awesome, yep I've been looking all over the net for an implementation of Function 1!

Comment: @nom_nutella; You should not edit the question after getting answers. It may mislead users to downvote.

Comment: @haccks Thank you for letting me know that, I'm new posting around here so I don't know these things.. 

and thanks paddy for taking care of the rollback

Comment: @nom_nutella If you "always forget the type", then you should know by now to look to see if you forgot the type, especially when the compiler points you right at the line where the type is missing.

Comment: @nom_nutella "I fixed my code for anyone who may need this type of thing in the future" -- How could that help anyone? The answers say what's wrong with the erroneous code ... correcting the code in the question makes the question and answers nonsensical, and no one could possibly be interested in your code *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning value from function1 when its return type is void? If problem still persists tell exact line where error occurs.